# Some C functions in iOS duplicated as #define

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, c-preprocessor, memcpy

**C** functions like memcpy and memset are available as **C** functions as well as #define in iOS:

For example the #define memcpy, under the hood, is:

```
#define memcpy(dest, src, len)                  \
((__darwin_obsz0 (dest) != (size_t) -1)             \
 ? __builtin___memcpy_chk (dest, src, len, __darwin_obsz0 (dest))   \
 : __inline_memcpy_chk (dest, src, len))
```

1. I gather there is some memory checking here but can someone shed some additional details on why it is better than a memcpy alone (where is the value added)?
2. More importantly, when to use which?

Comment: technically, it is a `#define`, not a `typedef`. one is a preprocessor thing, the other is a compiler thing.

Comment: Correct. Thanks. I corrected the question. I understand the step it is handled in. Yet when the pre-processor replaces the #define, is that code better than memcpy. Back to my questions....

Comment: see if [this](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Object-Size-Checking.html) can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you `#undef` the macro, or call it like this `(memcpy)(args...)`, it will always use the macro variant.

I would personally just use the maco - it's intended to be fast and efficient, and will work as you expect.

Comment: Or, unless you say `void* (*func)(void*, const void*, size_t) = memcpy; func(dest, src, len);`.  Which should succeed, i'd think.

Comment: Hmmm, did not know the role of parentheses here. So enclosing a function name in parentheses automatically excludes a #define with the same name?

Comment: @Spectra Indeed it does. I wish I had the documentation for it, but you can try it out for yourself.

Comment: It only excludes the macro if the macro itself takes parameters. For exampe:
`#include <stdio.h>`  
  
`void foo() {`  
`   printf("foo called\n");`  
`}`  
   
`void bar() {`  
`   printf("bar called\n");`  
`}`  
  
`int main() {`  
  
`   #define foo bar`  
`   foo();      //Calls bar()`  
`   (foo)();    //Also calls bar()`  
  
`   #undef foo`  
`   #define foo() bar();`  
  
`   foo();      //Calls bar()`  
`   (foo)();    //Calls foo() (i.e. the macro was blocked)`  
  
`   return 0;`  
`}`

Answer (score 2):

Those names, such as `__inline_memcpy_chk`, are used by the compiler to help it optimize uses of `memcpy`. They are special names that corresponding to built-in features of the compiler. They assist it in converting certain uses of `memcpy` into code that is faster than calling the `memcpy` library routine. The result might be simple move instructions or, even more efficiently, simple changes of information inside the compiler, so that it knows a copy of a value is available in a register.

If you undefine the macro `memcpy` so that these built-in features are not used, which is permitted by the C standard, the `memcpy` routine will still work, but it may be less efficient than if you left it alone.

Generally, you should not try to call these internal names yourself. They have been designed and defined to make the normal use of `memcpy` efficient.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions,

1) I have no additional details, but peeking under the hood like that violates the abstraction the authors have provided for you.  You want memcpy, you've got memcpy as they've provided it there, implemented with the snippet you're showing.  If you're curious how it works, you can dig into it, but because you asked "when to use which" I suspect you're trying to figure out something that works in practice.  Which gets to the answer to your second question...

2) You should use memcpy(dest, src, len).  Don't hack around the #define and use the underlying code in a way that was not intended.  You're provided with memcpy() as it is there; for you, that *is* memcpy.